# Cannot Choose Operating System After Reinstall

Tags: startup

I re installed Ubuntu.  I cannot choose the operationg system at bootup. windows is installed. I cannot choose Ubuntu any reason?

Answer (score 1):

are you able to get into windows? if you can't get into windows  you should first fix that problem and i might be able to help you with that just let me know.

if you are able to boot into windows then we can focus on booting into Ubuntu. Either use a bootable USB or a DVD/CD with Ubuntu on it and boot from that. hit either the F2, F12, Esc or possibly another key depending on your computer when you first turn it on (it should tell show you on your screen on initial bootup which button to press). You can then choose to boot from USB or CD depending on what you have Ubuntu on. Then go into a live Ubuntu session and open a terminal and run these commands to operate boot-repair:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

once you have done that you can then run boot-repair in the terminal with this

```
boot-repair
```

click on the recommended repair button and hopefully that should work for you.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Answer (score 0):

Try going into your boot menu f2 i think at startup, I had that happen on my xp machine turned out I my live cd md5 sum was jacked up. If you still can't choose which os to boot from try using a usb stick. I'm a noob so hopefully some one with more knowledge can be of better help.

Comment: Thanks for the input to put the q at the top of the list.

Comment: It's not necessarily F2. It's escape on one of my computers and F12 on another. It just depends on what the manufacturer has chosen. You could Google to find out what it is for your particular computer or (probably easier) just watch the screen when it reboots.

Comment: Generally it's, f2, f12, ESC, or DELETE. some computers will show it first thing on boot up (which is a very short window of time) before it begins to boot into an OS or bootloader.

Answer (score 0):

If you can boot a live cd or usb then you could possibly install grub bootloader. try this link --- http://ubuntuguide.net/how-to-restore-grub-2-after-reinstalling-windows-xpvistawin7 --- to get grub up and running.

Comment: This link also gives a way to do it from windows.